# Safari Jquery event handler delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

i'm facing an issue which has been quite unknown to me.

In my example http://studio-a-h.de/kirby-test/projects/morning-has-not-dawned-yet you see a photoslider.

**If you click on "Index"** an overlay with the image index is about to be displayed.
In chrome and Firefox everything is fine, but Safari shows the overlay with a delay of appr. 500ms and it seems that there is an extra delay, even when the div is already visible.

Are there any known bugs with Safari and jquery? In my research i hardly found something, beside the iOS Mobile delay bug.

Would be great if someone has an idea. Maybe it is a css issue i did not find?

Best regards

Comment: I don't see this issue on an iPhone 7. Is this just clicking a link on he index list and it scrolls to the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try and add a rule to adapt the browser in-advance, prior to that opacity change.

Use the `will-change` **[property](http://caniuse.com/#search=will-change)** like so:

```
.main {
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

This will tell the browser that there is going to be some opacity changes to that div, so the browser can be ready for it before the opacity change rules are met.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried it with your recommendation but it feels still very buggy - only in Safari. maybe you have another way how to fix this?

Comment: Have you reset your browser caching?

Comment: Hi, 
yes i deleted the cache and still use it here 
http://studio-a-h.de/kirby-test/projects/morning-has-not-dawned-yet

will change seems to have no Safari support
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/

Comment: To be honest, I've tried it on safari and it doesn't seem to twitch. Also, check this http://studio-a-h.de/kirby-test/projects/morning-has-not-dawned-yet

What I mean is - I am unable to reproduce your issue so that I can look for a solution to it.

Comment: Thats interesting, which version do you use? On Version Safari 10.0.3 it seems to be buggy when i click on index.

Comment: I just realized the issue, I was looking into something else (You said click on index, I wasn't doing that). Have you tried using a different version of jquery? And can you list out all of the JS files that you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to stop working for today. I will write you tomorrow! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi again, with my jquery version everything seems to be fine. I guess the codeline below might be the problem




'
 $('a.panel-index--toggle').click(function() {
  $('.panel--index').toggleClass('index-is-open');
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
 });

 $("a.index--close").click(function() {
  $('.panel--index').removeClass('index-is-open');
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
 });
'

Comment: Try and use the following:

`$('.panel-index--toggle').on('click', function () {
 $('.panel--index').toggleClass('index-is-open');
 $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});
$(".index--close").on('click', function () {
 $('.panel--index').removeClass('index-is-open');
 $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
});`

Comment: Thx for your answer, the issue is still occuring. I tried it without isotope as well, but nothing changed.

Comment: Interesting - when i'm in the safari inspect tool and switch on/off opacity, or visibility the lag appears in the same manner. It seems to be a rendering issue.

Comment: I tried it with
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

but nothing changes...

Comment: I tried a lot of different verions and found out that Isotope seems to be the problem... 

I will do some research about it

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much exprience using isotope to say what the issue is. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, i can update the topic. It was not a jquery problem.
I used hardware acceleration with translateZ(0) and this caused a super bad Safari performance on animations. 

Now i just have the problem that it lags like hell on scroll  :(

Comment: set all your transforms to 3D if you haven't

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It was not a jquery problem. I used hardware acceleration with translateZ(0) and this caused a super bad Safari performance on animations. Now i just have the problem that it lags like hell on scroll :(